# Spring Security check if User has RoleGroup

Tags: grails, spring-security, user-roles

I have the domain:

User *hasOne* RoleGroup *hasMany* Role

- **Exemples:**

**RoleGroup:** Admin, Professional, Client, ...

**Role:** ROLE_ACTION_1, ROLE_ACTION_2, ...

How I check if a user has a RoleGroup with annotation @Secured?

I need to check if user contains all roles of RoleGroup?

User class:

```
class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    static constraints = {
        password blank: false, password: true
        username blank: false, unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
        version false
        table schema: "CA"
    }

    static transients = ['springSecurityService']

    transient springSecurityService

    transient boolean enabled = true
    transient boolean accountExpired
    transient boolean accountLocked
    transient boolean passwordExpired

    String username
    String password
    RoleGroup profile

    Set<RoleGroup> getAuthorities() {
        [profile]
    }
}
```

RoleGroup class:

```
class RoleGroup implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    String name    

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        RoleGroupRole.findAllByRoleGroup (this)*.role
    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you saying if spring supports a role group which is a list of roles ?Not sure abt that.  I would do a database design for roles extending roles or a role group, then treat them as role in spring. Spring supports list of roles -> @Secured ({"Admin", "Professional"})

Comment: Paste your User domain class source and example User class instance.

Comment: I paste my classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not fully grasped spring security.

When using annotation - first annotation must be enabled in the config - this is the case by default.

You then secure either an entire controller or a controller action using something like this

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER'])
```

It has no way of working out all of what the user has as authority groups.

Although in the code you pasted in the RoleGroup class you have :

```
getAuthorities()
```

I have tweaked my User domain class and added the following:

```
   Set<RoleGroup> getAuthorities() {
        UserRoleGroup.findAllByUser(this)*.roleGroup
    }
    Set<RoleGroup> getAuthoritiesNames() {
        UserRoleGroup.findAllByUser(this)*.roleGroup?.name
    }
```

So when I have a user

i.e. User user=User.get(1L)

```
def authorities = user.getAuthorities()
println "user ${user} has ${authorities}"
```

which is a list containing all the authorities

```
if (authorities.contains('ROLE_USER'))  {
println "WOOHOO"
}
```

With spring security you could also use it within gsps:

```
  <sec:ifAllGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN">
show something
</sec:ifAllGranted>
```

So back to your question:

You have :

```
Set<RoleGroup> getAuthorities() {
        [profile]
    }
```

Is that something you have in put in place ?

From where it is :

```
class RoleGroup implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    String name    

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        RoleGroupRole.findAllByRoleGroup (this)*.role
    }    
}
```

This should list you all the authorities

```
User user = User.get(1L)
def authorities = user?.profile?.getAuthorities()
```